# Error with running installed ClickOnce Application?

Tags: sql-server, download, installation, sql-server-ce, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce Application that installs, but when it tries to run, I receive 2 error messages followed by an Unhandled Exception break message.

[image]

I have read through KB article 974247 many times, tried several variations of installing SQL Server Compact SP2 x86 & x64, but still no go.

The only thing I have found is that on 64-bit machines it is necessary to install the 32-bit version of SQL Server Compact before the 64-bit can be installed.

Can anyone assist me with this?

The Application was developed in VS2010, the computer OS is Windows7.

Comment: Let's start with:

GAC: What version of ADO.NET provider have you in there? x86 or x64?
Are you deploying a x64 or a x86 application?

Comment: The version in the error message refers to SQL CE version 4.0, so installing 3.5 SP2 will not solve anything.